# How to read AWS RegionEndpoint from appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, blazor, asp.net-core-configuration

Blazor Server. 
I have a model

```
public class S3SvcConfiguration: IS3SvcConfiguration
{
    public string AccessKey { get; set; }
    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
    public RegionEndpoint RegionPoint { get; set; }
    public string S3Url { get; set; }
}
```

But when I read the appsettings.json configuration the RegionEndpoint  is null:
The RegionEndpoint  is AWS type.

```
"S3SvcConfiguration": {
    "RegionPoint": "us-east-2",
    "S3Url": "http://myhost:9000",
    "AccessKey": "qwerty",
    "SecretKey": "qwerty123"
  },
```

I read it

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSingleton<IS3SvcConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("S3SvcConfiguration").Get<S3SvcConfiguration>());
    services.AddScoped <IS3FileSvc,S3FileSvc> ();
}
```

ALl values populated but RegionPoint is null.
How to read appsettings.json configuration to populate the RegionPoint  value?

Comment: What does the `RegionEndpoint ` type look like? The JSON needs to correspond to that.

Comment: Also, the property is called `RegionPoint` in your JSON, not `Region*End*Point`

Comment: RegionEndPoint  is a type. The variable is RegionPoint;

Comment: You have a complex type in the class but a simple string in the JSON.

Comment: @Oleg what does `RegionEndpoint` look like?

Comment: That is AWS data type https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html

Comment: @Oleg [RegionEndpoint ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Amazon/TRegionEndpoint.html)  is part of their custom configuration but you try to populate it from a simple string when they would have had code to handle that. Consider changing the approach to manually convert that string to the desired value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RegionEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Amazon/TRegionEndpoint.html)   is part of their custom configuration but you try to populate it from a simple string when they would have had code to handle that.

Consider changing the approach to manually convert that string to the desired value

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    S3SvcConfiguration config = Configuration.GetSection("S3SvcConfiguration").Get<S3SvcConfiguration>();
    string region = Configuration.GetValue<string>("S3SvcConfiguration:RegionPoint");
    config.RegionPoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region);
    services.AddSingleton<IS3SvcConfiguration>(config);

    services.AddScoped <IS3FileSvc,S3FileSvc> ();
}
```